# Content security policy and using nonce

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-security-policy, nonce

I'm trying to add content security policy to my .Net core 3.1 project. I get the below error:

[image]

**this is my header :** content-security-policy: default-src 'self' *.fontawesome.com *.gstatic.com ; script-src 'nonce-R4nd0m' 'self' ; style-src 'self' https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css *.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito ;

**My master page:** < script nonce="R4nd0m" src="~/js/bundles/jquery.js" asp-append-version="true">

I'm trying to white list my jquery.js file but it doesn't seem to work. the only way I can make the project work is by adding 'unsafe-eval' to my headers which I don't want to do.

I have used nonce and it seems to work for inline scripts on the page but it still errors for my jquery.js file. What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**

**Call stack:** Ajax request using unobtrusive ajax package, here is the code:

```
<a href="/Users/Create" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-update="#dialog" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success="DialogModule.open(&quot;Create user&quot;);"><i class="fa fa-plus icon-spacing"></i>Add User</a>
```

Here is a picture of the area that errors:
[image]

This is generated by I assume unobtrusive ajax library.

Comment: `R4nd0m` isn't a nonce, but all you need to load that script is the existing `script-src 'self'` anyway. What's calling `Function`? Expand at the stack trace (or use your debugger).

Comment: Edited my comment for more information thanks :)

Comment: `data-ajax-success="DialogModule.open(&quot;Create user&quot;);"` is JavaScript in an arbitrary HTML attribute, which is essentially incompatible with a good CSP. If “Unobtrusive Ajax” allows you to attach listeners from an actual JavaScript file, you’ll probably be able to fix the problem by doing that.

Comment: I think you're missing the 'unsafe-eval' which might be the cause of the error. Add 'unsafe-eval' to the `script-src` directive like so:
`script-src 'nonce-R4nd0m' 'self'  'unsafe-eval'`

Comment: the error doesnt say the issue is that line though, it says EvalError. The line above would be a "inline" style or script which is not throwing an error anyway?

Comment: sagar1025 the 'unsafe-eval' key word is not safe to use I dont think. Everyone says you shouldn't use it.

Comment: The error doesn’t say the issue is that line because the actual `eval` operation is in library code, but that line *is* an issue.